# Updation Not Done inside Gridbox. Exception Handling Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have did a Edit/Update/Delete/Cancel in the gridbox. All the functionlaities are working fine. Except Updating.

When I Click, I get an error stating,

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user code.
Object Reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Here is the Code for updating the data's

```
protected void Show_Grid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int id = int.Parse(Show_Grid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    TextBox title_txt = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Title");
    TextBox Desc_Txt = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Description");
    DropDownList Prior_Drop = (DropDownList)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Priority");

    Update_todo(id, title_txt.Text, Desc_Txt.Text, Prior_Drop.SelectedValue);
    Show_Grid.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
private void Update_todo(int id, string title, string desc, string prior)
{
    string source = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=...//...//..//..//tododb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    SqlConnection dbconnect = new SqlConnection(source);
    string query = "UPDATE todolist SET Title='" + title + "', Description='" + desc + "', Priority='" + prior + "' WHERE id =" + id + " ";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, dbconnect);
    dbconnect.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In the Gridbox, while editing i gave TextBox with SingleLine for Title, TextBox with Multiline for Description & DropDown for Priority.
I get the error in this line

```
Update_todo(id, title_txt.Text, Desc_Txt.Text, Prior_Drop.SelectedValue);
```

Grid view markup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="Desc_Txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Prior_Drop" runat="server"
SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Priority") %>'>
<asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>High</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Medium</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Low</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priority") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Operation" ShowDeleteButton="True"
ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are either not getting one or all of the controls `title_txt`, `Desc_Txt` or `Prior_Drop`

Check if they are null or not before accessing them

You can have a check before calling update like this, however you have to make sure that it does not break your functionality in any way

```
if(title_txt!=null && Desc_Text!=null && Prior_Drop!=null)
{
   Update_todo(id, title_txt.Text, Desc_Txt.Text, Prior_Drop.SelectedValue);
   Show_Grid.EditIndex = -1;
   BindData();
}
```

**Update**

The mistake you are doing is, you are accessing the controls with wrong ids, use this and it will work

```
TextBox title_txt = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("title_txt");
TextBox Desc_Txt = (TextBox)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Desc_Txt");
DropDownList Prior_Drop = (DropDownList)Show_Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Prior_Drop");
```

Comment: I have used all these. Even I have reference in the remaining functionalities

Comment: Try putting the check and see if it works. I updated the code

Comment: Are you sure the controls you are trying to access is in the row that is getting updated? Post your grid view markup

Comment: `<asp:GridView ID="Show_Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="id" onrowcancelingedit="Show_Grid_RowCancelingEdit" 
            onrowdeleting="Show_Grid_RowDeleting" onrowediting="Show_Grid_RowEditing" 
            onrowupdating="Show_Grid_RowUpdating">`

Comment: `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Title">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="title_txt" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: I got the mistake you are doing! See the update part of your question.

Comment: And you did not update your question, you just put it here in comments. Please put your full gridview markup in your question itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112875/discussion-between-pawan-nogariya-and-sheik-m).